# Problems getting an object and modify it with Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a problem trying to make a query in parse then modify the object. i do this but i can have the problem.

```
var user   = request.user;
var ObjectX = Parse.Object.extend("ObjectX");
var objectx = new Parse.Query(ObjectX);
queryTandem.equalTo("user", user);

  queryTandem.find({
  success: function(results) {

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
      var object = results[i];
      object.set("variableInDb",new Date());
      object.save(null, {
        success: function(object) {
          response.success();          
        },
        error: function(error) {
          response.error("Error.1005. User not valid");
        }
      });
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    response.error("Error");
  }
```

I was trying using SaveAll outside of for but nothing work. always i got the same error:

```
Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object.
```

Anyone have an idea how i can fix that. may be it is not possible in this way i don't know.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give us the `results` outputs? That would be helpful.

Comment: The output is ok. it is a list of products in database. the problems is that i can update them.

Comment: Maybe it's an unparsed object, have you tried parsing it to JSON? `results = JSON.parse(results);`. **Note:** Do this before the `for` statement.